# Retrieve the second last record for each user from the database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table that holds username, updated date, and status as below:

### name |  Updated_on  |  Status

```
akg     29-NOV-10       Active
akg     13-JAN-12       NonActive
akg     10-MAR-12       Active
ems     23-JUL-12       NonActive
ems     10-SEP-10       Active
tkp     10-SEP-10       NonActive
tkp     13-DEC-10       Active
tkp     02-JUL-12       NonActive
tkp     24-SEP-10       Active
aron    12-JAN-11       NonActive
aron    07-NOV-11       Active
aron    25-JUN-12       NonActive
```

In this table user status is updated every time we change the status (ie a `username` can have many entries as shown in the table.

I would like the second last updated record for each user. ie for the above table, the result should be:

### name |  Updated_on  |  Status

```
akg     13-JAN-12       NonActive
ems     10-SEP-10       Active
tkp     13-DEC-10       Active
aron    07-NOV-11       Active
```

I'm really confused as I want to get the record of each users in this.

Is there any query which can be used for this?

Thank you

Comment: second last record or second record?

Comment: What happens when there's only one record for a given user?

Comment: @koderoid:second last updated record for each user.

Comment: @Gerard Yin:we can ignore that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try that, it's a bit verbose but it works:

```
SELECT
  name,
  max(Updated_on) as Updated_on,
  STATUS
FROM userstatus a
  WHERE (name, Updated_on) not in
  (select name, max(Updated_on) FROM userstatus group by name)
group by name, status
HAVING UPDATED_ON =
  (SELECT MAX(UPDATED_ON) FROM userstatus b where a.name = b.name
   and (b.name, b.Updated_on) not in
  (select name, max(Updated_on) FROM userstatus group by name)
  group by name);
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd98/27)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    rounda.*
  FROM
    userstatus AS rounda
    INNER JOIN userstatus AS roundb
      ON rounda.name=roundb.name
      AND rounda.Updated_on<roundb.Updated_On
  ORDER BY Updated_on DESC
) AS baseview
GROUP BY name
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd98/6)

Comment: This query is grouping by one only one field.  This is using a feature of MySQL called "Hidden Columns".  MySQL does *not* guaratee anything about the results.  It does not even guaratee that all the values in the non-aggregated columns come from the same record.

Comment: @GordonLinoff While this is **generally** true, it is not true in this **special case**: It is the combination of 1.) The inner query being resolved as as a sorted temporary table and 2.) the `GROUP BY` being driven solely by the row number of the inner temporary table. This guarantees, that grouping will chose the first value seen on execution as the field value for the hidden column. Basically I am (ab)using a deficiency in MySQL's query optimizer to achieve a deterministic behaviour. Is it beautiful? No. Is it reliable? Yes.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear that the values are arbitrary and indeterminate (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  Can you provide a reference that the values are determinate in the case of a subquery with an order by clause?

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this (also) with Oracle:

```
select name, updated_on, status
from (
  select name, updated_on, status,
         row_number() over (partition by name order by updated_on desc) as rn,
         count(*) over (partition by name) as max_rn
  from userstatus
) 
where rn = max_rn - 1 
   or max_rn = 1;
```

This will actually work on a wide range of DBMS (including Oracle) - just not on MySQL.

Comment: For this query im getting an error given below ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"....Im getting this on the 5th line(on that count() line)

Comment: @anandkk: I forgot the `*` in `count(*)`