# How to get the second last record per group?

Tags: mysql

I have an table called **DemoTable** contains some fields like **com_name**, **updated_date**, **demo_var**,  I queried on it like

```
select * from DemoTable where demo_var=100;
```

so for example here i got 1000 records. On this 1000 record i want to query to get the last updated row of **com_name** based on **updated_date**

My table looks like

```
id   demo_var   com_name   updated_date

1     100         XYZ         2017-11-10

2     100         XYZ         2017-11-09

3     100         ABC         2017-10-10

4     100         ABC         2017-10-11

5     150         AJD          2017-11-11
```

First I want to fecth where demo_var=100 and get the different com_name which are last before updated ones.

For example like

```
2     100         XYZ         2017-11-09

3     100         ABC         2017-10-10
```

I want these two records to be fetched.

Comment: if id field is a auto increment value then you can use order by id desc limit 0,1

Comment: You want last updated records but your result said otherwise.

Comment: Your expected output is against your statement it shows with older updated_date

Comment: I changed the question, I want last before updated record

Comment: Do you mean "second last"? And did your searches really not find any info on how to do this? For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453231/select-the-second-last-record-in-each-group / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087627/second-last-records / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325142/retrieve-the-second-last-record-for-each-user-from-the-database

Comment: ya second last. I have tried but i didn't get, so if anyone helped me it would be nice

Comment: What have you tried? [Edit] your post to show it and why it didn't work. That way, people might avoid telling you things you already know and/or already discounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve second latest row per group you can use following query

```
select a.*
from demo a
where  a.demo_var = 100
and (
    select count(*) 
    from demo b
    where b.demo_var = 100
    and a.com_name = b.com_name
    and case when a.updated_date = b.updated_date
        then a.id > b.id 
        else a.updated_date < b.updated_date
        end
) = 1 /* here 1 is for second last , 0 for latest and so on */
```

> Note it compare rows by `updated_date` so if there are 2 rows for same updated_date and com_name then i have used id column to pick the second latest row and is assume that id column is set to auto increment by default

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7acb5b/4)

Answer (score 1):

Following query will work:

```
select t.demo_var,t.com_name,max(t.updated_date)
from
    (
    select demo_var,com_name,upddated_date
    from DemoTable
    where demo_var=100
    and (com_name,updated_date) not in (select com_name,max(updated_date)
                                        from DemoTable
                                        where demo_var=100
                                        group by demo_var,com_name
                                       )
    )t
group by t.demo_var,t.com_name;
```

Comment: Not very scalable though

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I know. I am trying come up with better solution.Will update here once I figured.

Comment: You have written only for id 1. I want dynamic query

Comment: You asked only for `demo_var=100`. If you want result for each `demo_var`, just remove both `where` clause from query and it'll work

Comment: Please try the edited query.